# CSS alignment issues from Firefox version 57 onward

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-quantum

I have a webpage and one of the element in it had the following style:

```
{
  width: 100%;
  min-width : 100%;
  height : 30px;
}
```

This was working perfectly with all the zoom options in Firefox versions prior to 57. But with Firefox version 57 and above, the alignment is completely distorted and is changing with zoom options. Can you please assist on this?

Comment: The issue is seen in RedHat 7.4 OS

Comment: Why are you only sharing this piece of css? Did you already narrow down the problem and realized that this css is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Yes. with older versions of firefox, this CSS works. Whereas with newer versions like 57 and above, It is expecting the height to be more than 40px(This causes a issue in older versions)

Comment: Please extend your sample code to the point where it can be [reproduced by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will either result in a good Firefox regression bug report, or in you realising what was wrong with your code.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: please refer to the below link where I have pasted a sample code:
https://pastebin.com/G9hRvLKL
In the code pasted I found that, in the styleClass "attributeRow" in the code pasted ,
Height and min-width have been defined as 30px and 100% respectively.
These values provide desired proper alignment with firefox versions prior to 57.
But with 57 and above , alignment is distorted.
Hope this piece of info helps.